# Computational complexity of topological K-theory

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, at.algebraic-topology, computational-complexity

I am a novice with K-theory trying to understand what is and what is not possible.

Given a finite simplicial complex $X$, there of course elementary ways to quickly compute the cohomology of $X$ with field coefficients.  However, it is known that computing the rational homotopy groups of $X$ is at least $NP$-hard (in fact, at least $\# P$-hard), simply because it is possible to reduce NP-hard problems to the computations of some rational homotopy groups.

For any of:
(1) Real K-theory,
(2) Complex K-theory,
(3) p-adically completed K-theory,
is there an algorithm to compute $K^0$ of a finite simplicial complex?  Is this algorithm polynomial-time?

If there is no known algorithm, is there at least evidence that any theoretical algorithm, should it exist, must be at least $NP$-hard?  In other words, is there any way to reduce an $NP$-hard problem to the calculation of some $K$ group?

Comment: Are you familiar with the Atiyah-Hirzebruch SS?

Comment: Yes, but only as a black-box.  I do not know an algorithm to compute differentials or solve extension problems.  Is this possible?

Comment: Probably not. The first differential is easy (for KU), it's determined by a cohomology operation, but I think the higher ones are algorithmically intractable and would describe higher-order cohomology operations. Maybe one should try to describe vector bundles on finite simplicial complexes combinatorially instead?


Comment: I have thought about this occasionally.  There is some reason to think that there might be a tractable combinatorial construction of a minimal Kan complex of homotopy type $\Omega^\infty(KU/2)$.  From that it should be possible to determine the computational complexity of $(KU/2)^*(X)$.  Odd primes might be possible as well.  I have various kinds of calculations related to this, but no real conclusion.

Comment: Dominique Arlettaz has a result regarding the order of differentials in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence, see "The order of the differentials in the Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence". I would imagine that one might be able to make certain conclusions if you assumed enough about the torsion of the homology of the space. However, on rereading your question I realize this is not so much what you were interested in. Thought I'd mention the paper of Arlettaz just in case though.

Comment: Have you looked at Gunnar Carlsson's stuff? They have this software for computing homology; maybe it could be made to work with K-theory, or maybe they've addressed the computational complexity and that could help you bound the complexity of K-theory. Here is a link: http://comptop.stanford.edu/. In a similar vein, Rob Ghrist has done work on algorithms for cohomology theory, but I'm not sure if he's addressed computational complexity or not. Last thought: at the JMM last year there was a special session about K-theory and electrical engineering. Maybe those guys have looked into this question

Comment: Link: http://jointmathematicsmeetings.org/meetings/national/jmm2012/2138_program_ss37.html

Comment: Just thought I'd add a citation for the fact that rational homotopy groups of simply-connected spaces are NP hard [here](https://doi.org/10.1016/S0040-9383(98)00059-7). In particular, this is not just some $\pi_1$ issue.