# Computing K-theory for cellular vector bundles

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, vector-bundles, kt.k-theory-and-homology

One of the most computationally convenient properties of singular cohomology $X \mapsto H^\bullet(X;\mathbb{Z})$ is the fact that one can extract it from a good cover $\{U_i\}$ of $X$ via Cech cohomology, thus bypassing any scary spectral sequences. Is there a similar algorithmic shortcut available for other cohomology theories? I'm mostly asking about the possibility of computing the complex $K$-theory of a finite simplicial complex $X$ in the presence of a good cover (without using the Atiyah-Hirzebruch SS).

There has been at least [one old question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/125745/computational-complexity-of-topological-k-theory) about this with no answers in sight, which doesn't sound too promising. Perhaps it will help if I propose a candidate definition for vector bundles on $X$:

**Def:** A vector bundle $V$ (of rank $n$) over a simplicial complex $X$ is a functor from the poset of simplices in $X$ to the group $\text{GL}_n(\mathbb{C})$. In other words, each face relation $\sigma < \tau$ is assigned an invertible complex $n \times n$ matrix $V_{\sigma<\tau}$ so that (**1**) the matrix $V_{\sigma < \sigma}$ is the identity for every simplex $\sigma$, and (**2**) the relation $V_{\tau < \gamma} V_{\sigma < \tau} = V_{\sigma < \gamma}$ holds across any triple $\sigma < \tau < \gamma$ of simplices.

Let's say I don't care about honest vector bundles on the geometric realization of $X$, and focus exclusively on these discrete guys which are constructible with respect to the fixed simplicial decomposition. Is there a non-spectral-sequencey way to compute the obvious notion of $K_\bullet(X)$ for the collection of all such vector bundles? Maybe we can at least compute Chern classes? I'm happy to assume that $X$ is a triangulated smooth manifold if that helps in any way.

Comment: The face relations act invertibly on one of your vector bundles, so this action factors through a localized category in which all these arrows have inverses.  This new category is the groupoidificaiton of the face poset.  If $X$ is connected, then this groupoid is connected, and hence equivalent to some group $G$.  A vector bundle in your sense is then the same as a complex representation of $G$.

Comment: @JohnWiltshire-Gordon with $G = \pi_1(X)$, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so, since the face poset geometrically realizes to a subdivision of $X$.

Comment: The "problem" with the definition is easily explained: You consider $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ as a discrete group. It is also true in topological spaces that every map $X \to BGL_n(\mathbb{C})$ (where $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ viewed with the discrete topology) factors homotopically over the one-truncation, which agrees with $B\pi_1(X)$ if $X$ is path-connected. This way, you only get vector bundles with flat connection. If you want all, you have to map your face-poset/simplicial set into the singular complex of the topological $BGL_n(\mathbb{C})$ or any Kan complex equivalent to that.

Comment: @LennartMeier Sure, eventually I'd like to use a more complicated target category than the 1-truncation, but my impression is that the flat connection/local system case might be easier as a starting point.

Comment: @ViditNanda This might be true, but two words of "warning": 1) Going to the colimit $BGL(\mathbb{C})$ won't represent a cohomology theory.  (For this you would additionally have to take a plus construction and obtain algebraic K-theory of $\mathbb{C}$.) 2) You usually won't get anything "finitely generated". For example $[S^1, BGL_1(\mathbb{C})] \cong GL_1(\mathbb{C})$.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that singular cohomology agrees with Cech cohomology of a good cover $\mathcal{U}$ is a sort of generalised Mayer-Vietoris principle, as explained in Section II.8 and III.15 of Bott and Tu's "Differential Forms in Algebraic Topology". You get a double complex $C^*(\mathcal{U},S^*)$ of Cech-singular cochains, and the resulting Mayer-Vietoris sequence degenerates in two ways to give the result.

To generalise this to other cohomology theories, you'd need to use the spectral sequence of the pre-simplicial space
$$
X \leftarrow \bigsqcup_{i_0} U_{i_0} \stackrel{\leftarrow}{\leftarrow}\bigsqcup_{i_0<i_1} U_{i_0}\cap U_{i_1}\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\stackrel{\leftarrow}{\leftarrow}}\ldots
$$
as explained for example in [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/259903/8103). A friendly reference is

*Segal, Graeme*, [**Classifying spaces and spectral sequences**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF02684591), Publ. Math., Inst. Hautes Étud. Sci. 34, 105-112 (1968). [ZBL0199.26404](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0199.26404).

This doesn't completely avoid spectral sequences of course, but I believe if you follow it through it should give a way to compute K-theory just from the combinatorics of the good cover.

Comment: Thanks, Mark! I've seen Segal's paper before but didn't think it constituted a roadmap towards actual machine computation. Time to give it another look...